# How to delete every nth row from result set?

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression, window-functions, sql-delete

I have state data from IoT devices (home assistant) logged multiple times a day (depending on device) and retained for 1 year. I'm trying (for devices that log frequently) to keep 1 month of every state change, but for data older than 1 month delete every other state change.

Excerpt from database:

| state_id | entity_id | last_updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2342932 | sensor.climate_outside_humidity | 2022-11-12 04:13:46.598786 |
| 2063613 | sensor.climate_outside_humidity | 2022-10-28 03:02:47.756064 |
| 1984952 | sensor.climate_outside_temperature | 2022-10-20 07:32:51.674016 |
| 925115 | sensor.climate_outside_humidity | 2022-07-25 09:54:01.095297 |
| 1897854 | sensor.climate_outside_humidity | 2022-10-11 17:28:13.448728 |
| 2005628 | sensor.climate_outside_temperature | 2022-10-22 12:37:21.027465 |
| 1071454 | sensor.climate_outside_humidity | 2022-08-04 13:16:02.885636 |
| 1663793 | sensor.climate_outside_temperature | 2022-09-17 14:36:05.900979 |
| 1756081 | sensor.climate_outside_temperature | 2022-09-27 23:17:25.688069 |
| 2372362 | sensor.climate_outside_temperature | 2022-11-14 02:28:16.034873 |

My query so far :

```
SELECT state_id, entity_id, last_updated
FROM "states"
WHERE entity_id IN ("sensor.climate_outside_temperature","sensor.climate_outside_humidity")
AND last_updated < date('now', '-30 day')
ORDER BY entity_id,state_id DESC
```

I'm sorting by `entity_id`, then `state_id` (as proxy for `last_updated` as it should be faster). This gives data older than 30 days I'd like to delete every nth row from:

| state_id | entity_id | last_updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1897854 | sensor.climate_outside_humidity | 2022-10-11 17:28:13.448728 |
| 1071454 | sensor.climate_outside_humidity | 2022-08-04 13:16:02.885636 |
| 925115 | sensor.climate_outside_humidity | 2022-07-25 09:54:01.095297 |
| 1756081 | sensor.climate_outside_temperature | 2022-09-27 23:17:25.688069 |
| 1663793 | sensor.climate_outside_temperature | 2022-09-17 14:36:05.900979 |

I could add modulus of `rowid` to `WHERE`, but `rowid` isn't row number in result but primary index on source table. So that wouldn't work. I need a computed index column on result set, but I don't know how.

Comment: Does your query return correctly the rows from which you want to delete every other row? Why do you order by state_id? Isn't entity_id enough since it is the primary key of the table?

Comment: If as you say entity_id is the primary key of the table then this query would return no more than 2 rows.

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want because your code does not match the description of your problem.

Comment: [ask] [mre] https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Ooops ... state_id is the primary key not entity_id, I have edited. Should make more sense now....

entity_id is the id of the device returning data
state_id is unique autoincrement key on table

Yes, in this example the query gives me the result set from which I want to delete every nth row (which is not same as every nth row from the table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to get the ranking of the rows returned by your query, filter the results to get only the even rows and delete only the filtered rows:

```
WITH 
  numbers AS (
    SELECT state_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY state_id DESC) AS rn
    FROM states 
    WHERE entity_id IN ('sensor.climate_outside_temperature', 'sensor.climate_outside_humidity') 
      AND last_updated < date('now', '-30 day') 
  ),
  ids AS (SELECT state_id FROM numbers WHERE rn % 2 = 0)
DELETE
FROM states
WHERE state_id IN ids;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/c6v3xjcP).

Comment: Aha! with line 3 edited to "SELECT state_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY entity_id,state_id DESC) AS rn" this works perfectly!

Comment: @user3171220 I suspect that you don't want to delete every other row of the resultset of your query as you say in your question but every other row of each entityid. If so, then the correct code would be: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY entityid ORDER BY state_id DESC) AS rn`

Comment: Correct again!
And I've also just realized that what I really want to do is to do this periodically / automatically, but obvs I only want to affect the section of rows that have not previously been culled ;)
Such a simple idea gets more complex by the minute.